# Get last-update timestamp from redshift tables

Tags: amazon-redshift, dynamic-sql

I'd like to monitor how stale our data are getting by setting up a query that spits out the last write to each table in Redshift.  Each table has a `created_at` field, and I can pull all table names via `pg_table_def`, but there's no way to set up dynamic sql in Redshift (eg `SELECT max(created_at) FROM {table})`.

I did a dive through the other admin tables and views, but nothing seems to address this.  I'm sure this is a solved issue though, anyone have a tip for how they put it together?

Comment: You would need to write an application to query a list of table names, then iterate through them and create a query for each table. It would just be a few lines of code in Python.

Comment: Do you need to do this dynamically? If it's a fixed list of tables you could union multiple select statements in a view.

Comment: @Nathan it's fixed as of right now, but our team will undoubtedly add/drop tables in the future and I'd rather not constantly be updating that list.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement for updating the last access times for tables using a `LAST_UPDATED` column in each table. Here is how I accomplished it:

```
UPDATE UPDATION_RECORD_TABLE SET LAST_MODIFIED = (SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATED) FROM %s) WHERE TABLE_NAME = '%s';
```

Here, UPDATION_RECORD_TABLE is a table having two columns, the name of the tables and their last update dates. The above SQL query when executed using Python code (using [pyscopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/)), the values **`%s`** can be replaced with the table name, after looping through a list of tables, which I fetched already using `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables`

Hope this helps.